# Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] in karma test afterAll

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following code in it's own file:

```
angular.module('app').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('cmx.use-json-server') === 'true') {
        const blacklist = window.localStorage.getItem('cmx.json-server-blacklist');
        const JSONServerBlacklist = blacklist ? JSON.parse(blacklist) : [];
        const JSON_SERVER_HOST = 'http://localhost:3000';
        const extraMessage = JSONServerBlacklist.length > 0 ? `except for the following: ${JSONServerBlacklist.join(', ')}` : '';
        console.warn(
            `WARNING: you are using JSON server. All requests are being routed to ${JSON_SERVER_HOST} \n${extraMessage}`
        );
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
            return {
                request: function (config) {
                    const url = config.url;
                    // ignore template requests
                    if (url.includes('.html') || JSONServerBlacklist.includes(url)) {
                        return config || $q.when(config);
                    }
                    config.url = JSON_SERVER_HOST + config.url;
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                }
            };
        }]);
    }
}]);
```

This code works fine, and is not under test, but the files existence causes the following error when I run my Jasmine tests in Karma:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/nomod?p0=app
```

When I cut and past the `.config()` block unmodified into another js file, this problem goes away. What is causing the problem here? From the error message it appears that there is something wrong with the `angular.module('app')` part, but this is also pasted from an existing file that does not cause any issues.

Comment: Might be something out of order. Is this file being loaded before you do your `angular.module('app', [...])` In testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally clear as to why, but I was able to solve the problem by making it a new module by changing:

```
angular.module('app')
```

to:

```
angular.module('JSONServerInterceptor', [])
```

The reason I am not totally clear why this solved my problem is that my project has multiple other files that use `angular.module('app')` in the same was as in my code above, and I even tried pasting my code into one of those files - which still caused the test error.